# C++. How to know where a method/variable is defined? or how to ask the compiler about it?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, methods, compilation

In our very large framework, tracking down a bug in one package, I ended up on a call to a function.

This function is not defined in the package I'm working on, and a search over the package itself does not give me any clue about the place where that function is defined in the framework.

So apparently it's defined in another package somewhere inside the framework.

I have to know what this function exactly does, so I would like to "ask" the compiler where it is defined. ...because the package compiles fine, so the function must be defined somewhere! ;-)

How can do that?

Comment: It might help if you could describe your development environment in a bit more detail. E.g., which compiler are you using? For example Visual Studio has “go to definition” or some similar wording in its context menu that will take you to the right place, taking into account preprocessor macros etc.

Comment: Hi Christopher. I'm using the Eclipse IDE, but for the framework we use a distributed and somehow custom compilation tool called CMT (which call gmake internally). And it's not easy to link Eclipse with such a distributed framework. But the "gdb" hint by Martin made the job. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "ask" the compiler (and/or linker) where it is defined by creating a second definition of that function.

```
void foo();

void foo() // function you are looking for
{
}

void foo() // second definition to tease the compiler.
{
}
```

Now the compiler will complain and give you a hint

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void foo()’:
main.cpp:7: error: redefinition of ‘void foo()’
main.cpp:3: error: ‘void foo()’ previously defined here
```

The linker will now complain and give you a hint.

```
b.cpp:(.text+0x6): multiple definition of `foo()'
```

Now you know the real `foo' is in b.cpp.

But what if it is defined in a header file?

main.cpp:

```
#include "secret.h"

void foo() // second definition to tease the compiler.
{
}
```

secret.h:

```
void foo() // function you are looking for
{
}
```

Now the compiler will find it for you:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void foo()’:
main.cpp:3: error: redefinition of ‘void foo()’
secret.h:1: error: ‘void foo()’ previously defined here
```

Now you know the real `foo' is defined in secret.h.

Comment: very nice trick!! Thanks a lot Eddy! And, I have to admit, very straightforward way to discover where a method was defined! +1 and accepted answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

I would set a breakpoint on the call of the "unknown" function and run a debugger. When the debugger stops at this point I would step into the function and print the backtrace. Than it should step into the function and give you the information of the source file the function is located.

With gcc/gdb you run your app like this:

```
gdb ./path_to_your_app/app_binary
(gdb) break SourceWhereYourFunctionIsCalled.cpp:123
(gdb) run
(gdb) step
(gdb) bt
```

And with Visual Studio it is much more easier. Just set a breakpoint and step into with F10 as far as I remember. Than the source file will be automatically opened.

I assume that you have a debug version.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a linux/unix platform, you could also run the following command on the binary:

nm -a -l binary | grep symbol

example:

```
$ nm -a -l test | grep main
                 U __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000004004a8 T main /home/mwijekoo/tests/sizeof/test.c:6
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, my first try will be to try a global search in your framework, like this :

```
grep -R "MyMethod" /my/framework/root/path
```

Or use a fast and easy [grep replacement](http://betterthangrep.com/).

Second you can try nm on the executable or library :

```
nm -al myexe
```

The `-l` option should give you files and line number, if you have compiled with debug options.

my2c

Answer (score 1):

Most IDE can search code for specific methods or definitions. A compiler wouldn't normally do this. Try the context menu after selecting the method in the code.
The function can be defined in a linked in library. In that case you cannot access the code, unless you decompile it.

I need to know which compiler you use and which IDE etc.